# marcador google maps javascript al estilo uber

Tags: google-maps

necesito hacer en una pagina web un mapa con marcadores que se muevan segun la ubicacion del usuario en el mapa. como los uber en el mapa de la aplicacion uber.

intente hacer esto pero se ve mal.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = app.ubicacion;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  setInterval(mar,250);

  function mar() {
      var image = 'img/taxi2.png'
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: app.username,
        icon: image
      });
      setInterval(rem, 200)
      function rem() {
        marker.setMap(null);
      }
      console.log(myLatLng.lat)
  }

}
```

en español creo un marcador y lo borro y lo vuelvo a crear por si se ha actualizado la ubicacion.

quisiera saber si hay otra forma de hacerlo??

Comment: Hola Wilberth, bienvenido. Dices "intente esto pero me va mal" . Puedes explicar mejor eso? Por qué te va mal ?

Comment: gracias hola. en realidad dije que se VE mal porque yo quiero que el marcador "camine" en vez de aparecer y desaparecer mas adelante.

Comment: Ah, pues explicalo mejor en la pregunta

Comment: gracias la verdad no se como explicarlo.

Comment: Tal cual me dijiste en el comentario. Recuerda que todo lo relevante ha de ir en la pregunta. trata a los comentarios como si puedieran desaparecer en cualquier momento.

Comment: Entendido para la proxima. Gracias.

Comment: No sabes eso de: No dejes para mañana lo que puedes hacer hoy? xDD estás a tiempo de editar tu pregunta. Que hayas encontrado solucion no hace que la pregunta sea asi para siempre. Que te hayan entendido no quiere decir que te hayas explicado bien ya que "a buen entendedor, pocas palabras bastan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad es más fácil de lo que parece. Una vez que has creado el marcador solo tienes que ir actualizando su posición según vayas obteniendo datos actualizados. Para ello puedes usar el método [`setPosition`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) sobre el marcador.

Comment: muchas gracias, no lo he probado pero creo que eso es lo que ocupo. porque todavia no se como aplicarlo.

Comment: sera como map.setPosition(nueva posicion)  ??

Comment: marker.setPosition(ubicacion);

Comment: Si, según la documentación que te he puesto en la respuesta (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) es `setPosition` con la ubicación (latitud y longitud).

Comment: Gracias. Y para hacer setposition a multiples marcas.? Me podrias orientar?

Comment: Tienes que hacer el setPosition en cada marcador. Lo mejor es que te guardes los objetos `marker` en un array para que los puedas recorrer y actualizar.

Comment: muchas gracias, es correcto. jeje muy amable de su parte!! bendiciones